# equivalent to deprecated compileComponentAsync for dynamic component loading

Tags: angular

I have used the below code in order to load dynamically components in my app. As you may know, compileComponentAsync is deprecated in RC6. I want to find a similar solution. Maybe I should use compileModuleAsync. But I couldn't find  something. Has anyone an idea?

```
this.compiler.compileComponentAsync(component)
    .then(factory => {
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
        this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
...  ...
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-component-with-angular2-rc5/38888009#38888009

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you may use `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` it returns `ModuleWithComponentFactories`.

```
this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module).then(_module => {
            _module.componentFactories => Gives factory for all the components which are exported from the module.
        });
```

[Read more about it here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Compiler-class.html#!#compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync-anchor)

Hope this helps!!